Default Button and Kill Focus handler Edit Field in Dialog when Enter pressed?
In the case of having an Edit Control with a Kill Focus Handler and an OK button set as the default button, I noticed that when the focus is in the edit control (Want Return is not enabled) and the enter key is pressed, the Kill Focus Handler will not be invoked unlike when the OK button is clicked.
Is there a clever way to have the default button catch the Enter press to always cause a kill focus message on whatever the prior control was?
I guess the OK handler itself could do it, but is there another setting or trick to get that to work?
TIA!!

Just because you're a control doesn't mean that you're necessarily inside a dialog box.

This seems to work in the OnBnClickedOk() routine:
  // ensure focus set so kill focus called on other controls in case enter pressed
  if (GetFocus()!=&m_ctlButtonOk) {
    GotoDlgCtrl(&m_ctlButtonOk);
    PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, MAKEWPARAM(m_ctlButtonOk.GetDlgCtrlID(), BN_CLICKED), (LPARAM) m_ctlButtonOk.GetSafeHwnd())
    return;
  }

Does anyone see a potential issue doing this?
Interestingly, if you post any message and remove the return, it also works.  If you don't post, the change isn't seen in the ok handler.
